# eSata as network cable

Tags: speed, esata

Is it possible to use eSata as a network cable?

More specifically I would like to get they highest possible throughput between between 2 computers and was wondering if I could use as a way to transfer files.

Comment: FYI: 10gb nic(probably over fibre) is 1250mb/s double sata 3 max.

Comment: @cybernard esata not sata.  Esata is faster the Gigabit Ethernet at least from what I understand.

Comment: Although I won't be that surprised if this is impossible.

Comment: I said 10 gigabit ethernet not gigabit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Theoretically yes, practically it may be difficult.  Its certainly not simply "walk into computer store, get cable, plug in, configure IP's".

It appears to be possible to get and use a Sata Crossover cable - but I have not seen any drivers for one.

I've never dealt with the company, but I found http://www.techcable.com/HTML/SATA.htm shows they are selling external SATA to Infiniband 1x Cable assembly crossover pinout, so it looks like it would need to be a custom stack.

Would you not be better off channel-bonding some regular gigabit nics or getting a couple of [10 gigabit nics](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16833106075).  (While not cheap, its probably a lot cheaper then writing a network stack).

Of-course, if you are using this to transfer files, you might find it overkill as this is faster then most hard drives sustained throughput (I expect SSD's can easily saturate gigabit though)